# In python - finding the average median of 1000 samples of size n from a probability distribution P

Tags: python, function, statistics, average, median

I have a probability distribution P, and n is the sample size (specified as 10 in the below example).

I want to take n samples 1000 times, each time finding the median, and then averaging these to find the average of the sample medians.

For the below example, the average median should be approximately 3.75 - 3.8. My Function is returning around 3.5 and I can't figure out what the error is.

```
import random
def average_sample_median(n,P):

      repeat = 1000

      median_sum = 0
       
      for i in range(repeat):
    
        samples = random.choices(P, k=n)

        sum_p = 0
        
        for j, p in enumerate(samples):
    
            sum_p += p
        
            if sum_p == 0.5:
                median_sum += j + 1.5
                break
        
            if sum_p > 0.5:
                median_sum += j + 1
                break
            
     avg_median = median_sum / repeat
     
     return avg_median


print(average_sample_median(10,[0.2,0.1,0.15,0.15,0.2,0.2]))
```

Any help in figuring out what is going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. However, I'm curious to know why you aren't using the built in `statistics` module. It can be done with a simple `import statistics` statement. It can handle most statistical functions and constants, such as median and mean (average). I know this isn't really addressing your question, but hopefully you can use this to simplify your code.

Comment: I was trying to do the median calculation manually because I thought I had to but it turns out I don't. I've managed to get the correct answer using the built-in function. Thanks!